# Splitting a String discards characters

Tags: java

I'm trying to make my own calculator, and when I enter a fractional number ,and try to use the split method to split the string into two pieces (eg: 2.3+4.7) instead of splitting it into 2.3 and 4.7, it splits it into 2 and 7.
It doesnt matter if I use a dot or a coma, the result is always the same.

```
    String[] input = Num.split("[+-/%*]");
    double num1 = Double.parseDouble(input[0]);
    double num2 = Double.parseDouble(input[1]);
```

Please help, I have no clue how to solve this.

Comment: I think your RegEx is wrong, you need an escape character before the - as it is used to indicate a range in RegEx. If you're trying to split by + - / and * (standard operations) try `[+\-\/*]` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of those characters need to be escaped in regex, specifically `+`, `-` and `*`:

`String[] input = iNum.split("[\\+\\-/%\\*]");`

Answer (score 1):

Use `String[] input = iNum.split("[\\+\\-/%\\*]");`

Comment: A calculator that can only add is a poor calculator

Comment: Sorry changed that